# How to store a double loop result in a matrix with observations of two samples as rows and as columns

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, store

I'm a beginner with R. I wrote a double for loop for computing the dot product between each row of matrix x w.r.t. all the observations of sample X per time. I do not know how to store the results in a matrix having as columns the observations of sample X and as rows the rows of x. I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Here my code:

```
Dot.product <- function(x,X){
theta <- matrix(NA,nrow=nrow(x),ncol=nrow(X),byrow=T)
for(i in 1:nrow(X)){
for(j in 1:nrow(x)){
  theta[i,j] <- acos((sum(x[j,]*X[i,]))/(sqrt
        (sum(x[j,]*x[j,]))*sqrt(sum(t(X[i,])*X[i,]))))
 }}

return(theta)}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the dimensions wrong. Replace `theta[i,j]` with `theta[j,i]` and that should do it.

As a bonus, here is how I would have written your function, using vectorized functions instead of a double-loop:

```
Dot.product <- function(x, X) {
   a <- tcrossprod(x, X)
   n1 <- sqrt(rowSums(x * x))
   n2 <- sqrt(rowSums(X * X))
   acos(a / n1[row(a)] / n2[col(a)])
}
```

I have checked they produce the same results.